# Web Page Counter

Tags: html

What is a free and easy way to capture hits to a page on my site.
I do not want a counter to show up on the page.
I do have a db as part of the website.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use Google Analytics! [Link here](http://www.google.com/analytics/)

Totally free, better than anything you could hack together (probably)

Comment: i just made an account. do you know if i can see the hits right away, or does the application lag by a day?

Comment: It will tend to lag a day or so to start; it's unclear exactly when new hits become visible.

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics or the new upgraded HiStats ;)

Answer (score 1):

Some more details about what exactly you want to accomplish, as well as additional details about your server setup would be really helpful. There is a myriad of options available ranging from third party tools such as Google Analytics, Statcounter, etc. to simple counter script implementations in any of the popular scripting languages.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Google Analytics (if you want something simple) is to code a PHP script (or similar) to increment a field in the database whenever the site is visited.

Answer (score 1):

A Real-time alternative to Google Analytics is Woopra, which if you are lucky will let you into the beta testing.

http://www.woopra.com/

Features:

http://www.woopra.com/features/

Answer (score 1):

Or Mint http://www.haveamint.com

Answer (score 0):

Do you just not like the idea of a visible counter, or do you just not want a counter because it will start out with a low number?  http://www.sitemeter.com has a free counter that you can set to any number to start, or you can choose not to have it show a number, just the sitemeter icon and you can keep people from viewing your stats page.  They also have a paid option to have a hidden counter (I haven't tried the paid version). They can even send you weekly traffic updates if you want.